# Why can't I assign a variable to the input from prompt function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prompt, console.log

This is the code:

```
var name = window.prompt("What is your name").toLowerCase;
console.log(name);
```

It returns `undefined`, which seems confusing. Shouldn't it log to the console the string I type in?

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined, it should be the function `toLowerCase`, which you're not actually *calling*.

Comment: You miss function execution. `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `()` in `toLowerCase` call

```
var name = window.prompt("What is your name").toLowerCase();
console.log(name);
```